# Facebook api error on posting to wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    message => "Test" ,
    link => "link",
    name => "test",
    picture => "test pic",
    caption => "test",
    description => "test"
));
```

Error i am getting is
Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Sorry, this post contains a blocked URL

Error doesn't come when i run on localhost, it occurs only when i upload the code to server and then run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use  JS SDK**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

**Before that authenticate using OAUTH from**
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: how would this make any difference??

Comment: yeah the latest php sdk is not updated with OAUTH ,,,if you have mean no problem,, it won't through error message ,,,,,since it is older one you are getting that find the JS sdk ,,, it works well. though you use the php sdk ,,it won't conflict with JS SDK

Comment: But thing is i am able to post the message when running on localhost, only when i upload the code onto server, it gives the error. Hence i think issue is not with the code.

Comment: You can work with localhost. I did it, and i am able to post using the same code, which i mentioned above

Comment: ok then  picture => "test pic", put a full path of the image and test,in the same way for link too

Comment: Yup i gave the full path. All the fields are proper, as i am getting the output as required.

Comment: then you need to check for login redirect url, and return url,,,

Comment: i checked both, the only problem is with the code i mentioned, If i remove this code, everything works fine.

Comment: then avoid this code and follow JS SDK ,,your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the migration „Stream post URL security” enabled in your app settings?
If so, does the URL meet the requirements?

Comment: Yes i enable the stream post url security, but still the error is same

Answer (score 0):

1. does the user have autorized publish_stream  permission
2. have you modified your application in Fb dev interface in order to link server url to the app, instead of localhost?